# Spring 4 Java Config Transactions Proxy and Aspecj

Tags: proxy, aspectj, spring-transactions, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am creating a new project that uses aspectj transactions. It also uses legacy jars that contain services that are using the proxy method where an interface is required.

I am using java config and when I set

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

Then I get the following exception thrown with accessing the proxy style services from the legacy libs:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

If I change to:

@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.PROXY)

Then I don't get the problem but I can't then use the aspectj style transactions in my new project.

I've tried adding two `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotations with each adviceMode, but that is not allowed.

Here is the annotated class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mydomain")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class ApplicationConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
```

I've also added the aspectj maven plugin to the legacy project in the hope that it would handle the weaving at compile time and thus aspectj transactions would work. But this has not solved the problem.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to have spring deal with both advice modes? How would I do this?

Or is there another way around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the aspectj config on the legacy project.

When I ran mvn compile it became apparent. I had to add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

That got it working when compiled using maven, but I it would still not work in eclipse. I had to right click on the legacy project in eclipse:

```
Configure>Convert to Aspectj Project
```

Then I could deploy from eclipse and I had aspectj transactional support in the legacy jars.